# $NP\subseteq P/poly\implies PH\subseteq P/poly$

Tags: np, circuits

We know if $NP\subseteq P/poly$ then $PH=\Sigma_2$ Then We want to show that $\Sigma_2-SAT\in P/poly$. Now $$\phi\in \Sigma_2-SAT\iff \exists\ x\in\{0,1\}^{p_1(n)}\ \forall\ y\in \{0,1\}^{p_2(n)},\ \phi(x,y)=1$$
Now consider the language $L=\{(\phi,x)\mid \forall \ y\in\{0,1\}^{p_2(n)},\ \phi(x,y)=1\}$. This language is a $coNP$ problem. Since $P/poly$ is closed under complementation $L\in P/poly$. Hence there exists a polynomial-size circuit of $(\phi,x)$.

But at this point i am stuck how to get a polynomial size circuit of $\phi$ from $(\phi,x)$